# jQuery set max height per row

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a script that searches through some divs on a page, finds the tallest one and sets each div to that height, though i've come unstuck trying to run this function on a row by row basis. I have tried to add an `each` function per row but to no avail, currently every div gets changed to the tallest of them all.

```
<div class="items-row">
  <div class="span4"><p>Hello</p></div>
  <div class="span4"><p>Hello</p></div>
  <div class="span4"><p>Hello</p></div>
</div>
<div class="items-row">
  <div class="span4"><p>Hello</p></div>
  <div class="span4"><p>Hello</p></div>
  <div class="span4"><p>Hello</p></div>
</div>
```

With the jQuery as follows

```
$('.items-row').each(function(){
  var h = 0;    
  $('.items-row .span4').each(function(){
    if (h < $(this).height()){
      h = $(this).height();
    }
  });

  $('.items-row .span4').each(function () {
    $(this).css("height", h + 'px');
  });
});
```

Im 50% of the way there, any help would be greatly appreciated.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timwilks13/764Re/1/)

The fiddle runs off a button click and the css is for text purposes only.

*EDIT*

Removed unused classed from the html that were for test purposes only.

Comment: You already have first, second and third classes, so why not just do `$('.items-row.second .span4'` - or am I missing the point?

Comment: Oh sorry they were for test purposes i will edit the question accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: You could use a little snippet I made : http://jsfiddle.net/764Re/2/ Had to comment a line to achieve what you wanted. If it's for learning purpose, just say so! Ill explain the code.

Answer (score 1):

Give your `.span4` selectors some context by using the `this` keyword in your each loops. At the moment, you are setting the height of all of them to the tallest overall.

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('.items-row').each(function () {

        var h = 0;

        $('.span4', this).each(function () {

            if (h < $(this).height()) {
                h = $(this).height();
            }
        });

        $('.span4', this).each(function () {
            $(this).css("height", h + 'px');
        });
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/764Re/5/).

Comment: +1 for use of **$('.span4', this).each()** .. I didn't realise you could do that! (passing "this" as a 2nd param, so find sub-results of that element)

Comment: And I guess you could remove that last `+ 'px'`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/764Re/3/)

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('.items-row').each(function(){

    var h = 0;  

    $(this).find('.span4').each(function(){

        if (h < $(this).height()){
             h = $(this).height();
        }
    });

    $(this).find('.span4').each(function () {
        $(this).css("height", h + 'px');
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that inside the loop, you're accessing all the elements with `$('.items-row .span4')`, you need to access only the ones relevant for the current iteration with either `find()` or `$('.span4', this)`

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('.items-row').each(function () {
        $('.span4', this).css('height',
            Math.max.apply( Math, 
                $.map($('.span4', this), function(x) {
                    return $(x).height();
                })
            )
        );
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/764Re/4/)